Duplicate records in the table A, so need to update column with id 1 for one set of duplicate record and 2 for other set of duplicate records
merge into tableA src
using (select distinct p.*
       from 
           (select p.*,
                count(*) over(partition by CostName) as cnt
            from tableA p 
            where p.session_id = 9170765632313984400) p
       where cnt > 1) tgt on (src.session_id = 9170765632313984400
                              and tgt.name = src.name)

when matched then
    update
    set src.product_cost_id = pkgutils.getid()
    where src.product_cost_id is null;

I am able to get 5 duplicate records but the issue is for all the duplicate records the value is updated as 1,2,3,4,5 but I need 1 as id  for one set of duplicate (IPG-50849 Subscription OPEX RC) and 2 as id for other set of duplicate records(IPG-50849 Voice New OPEX NRC) and 3,4,5 for other not matched records.
enter image description here

Oracle and mysql are two different database products. Removed conflicting product tags

What's the database?

Oracle is the database

Any help for above query. please help in this

if the records are matching then we need to update the product cost id column with same id value rest all records with different id  using merge into, Can any one please help in this
